# NodeJS : Redis to verify unicity of a key

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm using Redis with nodeJS and I am looking for a way to check the existence of a record on a database. I've tried adding twice the same entry (sets hashes included) with the same key. Redis accepted the request both times.

Is there any way to make Redis refuse a seconde entry with the same key ?

Here is the code I run multiple times on the same Redis database :

```
 const redis = require('redis');
 // Defining client
 const client = redis.createClient();
 var multi = client.multi();

 client.hset("myId","myfield","myvalue", function(err, reply){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }else{
        console.log(reply);
      }
    });
```

Thanks

Answer By @ryanvincent :

```
 client.hsetnx("myId","myfield","myvalue", function(err, reply){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }elseif(reply == 1){ // 1 => means there is no entry in the database
                           // with this Id "myId"
        console.log(reply);
      }
    });
```

Comment: maybe interesting? http://redis.io/commands/hsetnx, also http://redis.io/commands/setnx

Comment: Have you tried using `client.exists` and `client.hexists`?

Comment: I have tried hexists, I guess I didn't use the right syntax for it. Anyway, @RyanVincent 's solution is working. thanks a lot man. I'm updating the question with your proposition